# Share tag NFC between two device Android

Tags: android, nfc

It is possible? 
I state that NFC is enabled on my phone and everything looks correct
I tried with an app called NFC TagWriter by NXP but don't work. 
I create a tag with this app and then I tried to listen with other device but don't work, then I installed same app on the other device but don't work. 
Please help me or suggested to me another way to do(share tag NFC).

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

The Android Beam™ feature allows a device to push an NDEF message onto another device by physically tapping the devices together. This interaction provides an easier way to send data than other wireless technologies like Bluetooth, because with NFC, no manual device discovery or pairing is required. The connection is automatically started when two devices come into range. Android Beam is available through a set of NFC APIs, so any application can transmit information between devices. For example, the Contacts, Browser, and YouTube applications use Android Beam to share contacts, web pages, and videos with other devices.

[Reference from Developer Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/nfc.html)

Also check this for [Blog](http://www.jessechen.net/blog/how-to-nfc-on-the-android-platform/) , it explains how to communicate between devices.

You can have (indepedent) p2p communication in 2 directions, and enableForegroundNdefPush is deprecated now; please, use [setNdefPushMessage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#setNdefPushMessage%28android.nfc.NdefMessage,%20android.app.Activity,%20android.app.Activity...%29)

Comment: Then why did you asked question here? @SaverioPuccia

Comment: Because I thought someone could help me.